# Do I need to front the cost of gas to sell a collection of NFTs

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, nft, hardhat

Forgive me if this has been asked before, if it has please provide any resources so I can learn more!

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the development process of creating an NFT.Say I want to create 10,000 randomly generated NFT's (like everyone else in the world right now) and release them to the public. Would I, the developer need to front the cost of the gas fees to put the NFT on the blockchain to sell to others, or would the gas fees be handled by the buyer when they pay whatever price I am asking then be sent to the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

Even to create an NFT you need to do a transaction in the Blockchain to register your nft which will cost gas fees.

Comment: It's true that minting an NFT will require gas fees but it's also possible to create an NFT factory contract that will allow users to mint (and pay for) their own NFT. So only the first contract gas cost needs to be paid.

Comment: @Bigbrotha Perfect! This is the answer I was looking for. So a "NFT factory contract". Very interesting, thank you so much!